# Are any solar medicine charms effective against Final Viridescence?

Tags: healing, exalted, disease, exalted-2e

In Exalted 2e, is there any solar medicine charm that can effectively cure (or aid in treating) Final Viridescence? I'm confused as to how it works, because while it initially calls itself a disease, it also says it follows the rules for infections. Solars don't seem to have any charms that affect infections - only sicknesses or poisons.

Dragon-bloods on the other hand, have charms specifically targeting infections, which makes me think that infections do not fall under the category of sicknesses or poisons. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Fatal Viridescence** is an infection.

From the Manual of Exalted Power - Infernal p110:

> This disease, sometimes called Scalp-Shed Tonsure,
>   is a **supernatural infection** without a natural vector.
>   [...] **See
>   Exalted, page 151, for basic rules on infections.**

As a consequence anything related to treatment is still on the table. Which gives us (restricted to the core book of Exalted 2e):

- Contagion-Curing Touch
- Flawless Diagnosis Technique
- Instant Treatment Methodology